# Capture image from Camera in HTC Desire Android device is not working?

Tags: android

i am doing a camera app which picks photo from camera i am working with the below code its working in samsung galaxy ace but in Htc Desire with Android OS 2.2 its not working,please help me anyone to resolve it,Thanks in advance.

```
**capture button Onclick:**
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String fileName = "IMG_" + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/");
cameraImageFile = new File(myDirectory, fileName);
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

**OnActivityResult:**
switch (requestCode) {
case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:

ImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(cameraImageFile.getAbsolutePath()));

}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing Uri of Image when starting Camera then get image as in `onActivityResult` :

```
     @Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

  if (CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST == resultCode) { 
     ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ReturnedImageView); 

      // Decode it for real 
     BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false; 

     //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent 
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cameraImageFile, bmpFactoryOptions); 

      // Display it 
     iv.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
     }    
   } 
}
```

Comment: imran how to handle these multiple screen support application in andorid any help from u?

Comment: @srinu : sorry dear i have no idea. but if you post it as a question then i'm sure you will quickly  get right answer.Thanks friend !!!:)

Comment: @srinu : if this answer help u you can mark it a answer for others help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();`
        `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");`
        `String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());`
        `imageName = dateNow + ".jpg";`
        `//Create path to store image in SDCard
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                + imageName;
startCameraActivity();`

`protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);`
        `Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`
        `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);`
        `startActivityForResult(intent,
                Globals.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }`

`@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {`
    `switch (resultCode) {`
            `case RESULT_CANCELED:`
                `Log.i("MakeMachine", "User cancelled");`
                `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
                `break;`
            `case RESULT_OK:`
`BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;`
        `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.i solved the issue,i made a small change in my code i am creating file in the sd card using 
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/");

there is no folder named as DCIM/Camera in Htc just changed the line as below its working fine

File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/");