# Getting Uri Null in capture photo from camera intent in samsung mobile

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am getting null in contenturi in samsung phones while capturing photo from camera but rest of others phones its working fine.

```
@Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    
        try
        {
             if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    Uri contentUri = data.getData();
                    if(contentUri!=null)
                    {
                        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };         
                        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);         
                        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);         
                        cursor.moveToFirst();         
                        imageUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
                    }

                    tempBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    mainImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
                    isCaptureFromCamera = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: it's a problem with samsung phones. See this for solution - http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/

Comment: And for HTC the mechanism can be different too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355887/capture-image-from-camera-in-htc-desire-android-device-is-not-working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android camera intent returns null... sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592734/android-camera-intent-returns-null-sometimes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This above code works in some mobile but does not work in samsung mobile in my case, so I implemented the common logic for all devices.

> After capturing the photo from camera, I implement a logic using Cursor and iterate the cursor to get the path of last captured photo from  camera.The below code works fine on any device.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do {
        uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
        photoPath = uri.toString();
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am also facing this issue to like I am checking app on MOTO G its not working but on Samsung devices its working So i do Below coding please check:-

Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

```
                try {
                    selectedImagePath = getPathBelowOs(selectedImageUri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (selectedImagePath == null) {
                    try {
                        selectedImagePath = getPathUpperOs(selectedImageUri);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


public String getPathBelowOs(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

/**
 * Getting image from Uri
 * 
 * @param contentUri
 * @return
 */
public String getPathUpperOs(Uri contentUri) {// Will return "image:x*"
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel,
            new String[] { id }, null);

    String filePath = "";

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }

    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```